# Flurry - User Acquisition Analytics (UAA) - No Installs

Tags: ios, analytics, flurry

We're using Flurry for analytics tracking.

Our SDK seems to be set up properly, as we are receiving and tracking events successfully.

We're trying to use User Acquisition Analytics (UAA) to track our installs, but after numerous attempts (over the course of many weeks), we are only getting 'clicks' and no 'installs'.

Is there anything special we need to do to get Flurry UAA working?

Our app is on the App Store, but we're trying to track downloads for beta installs. We're generating campaign URLs via the Flurry dashboard to our `.plist` files which are pointing to our beta IPA. Clicking on the link starts the app installation. We install the app, load it up, play around for a few minutes, then put it in the background and close it. After a few hours we see the 'click' register on the Flurry dashboard, but no installs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few thing to keep in mind when testing a UAA tracking link.

1) The click and the install must occur on the same device. 
2) It must be the first time the app has ever been launched on the test device. Removing and reinstalling the app will not count as an install. We have no visibility to to the install until the app is actually launched on the device.

The most common errors with UAA are using a test device that has previously had the app installed on it. And also we recommend starting the Flurry session when the app is first launched. Some publishers choose to start the Flurry session at some later time (such as after the user completes a registration form).

Send me an email to support@flurry.com and I may be able to test the campaign for you. Using a UAA tracking link in a plist file is not the intended purpose for these links, but I would like to hear the details.